# Matplotlib: reduce line graph into specific genders

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns: `'values'`, `'date'`, `'gender'`. I have some code that produces a line graph of two of the columns.

**Code**

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))

plt.plot(twelve_week_program.groupby(['date'])['values'].mean(), linewidth=5)
```

[image: Plot]

I want to include the `'gender'` column by plotting two different lines: one for males and one for females. The code at the moment does not consider the gender. It just plots each of the rows.

**Ideal output**

Same plot, just with two line graphs - one for each gender.

Comment: To add another line just write a new line of code `plt.plot(....)` under your first `plt.plot(twelve_week_program...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer:

```
plt.plot(df.groupby(
[df['date'], 'gender'])['values'].mean().unstack(), linewidth=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the index of the DataFrame to be the 'date' column, then use:

```
plt.plot(twelve_week_program.values[twelve_week_program.gender=='F']), linewidth=5)
plt.plot(twelve_week_program.values[twelve_week_program.gender=='M']), linewidth=5)
plt.show()
```

Providing 'F' and 'M' are how you've represented the column